# twig to print paragraph field in controller

Tags: theming, 8

new to d8. I have a result page where I need to print the field values of a paragraph field into my controller. The paragraph field is called `field_classrooms`.

text values print fine for example
`{{ teacher.field_last_name.value }}`

but when I need to print
`{{ teacher.field_classrooms.value }}`

I get

> User error: "target_id" is an invalid render array key in Drupal\Core\Render\Element::children() (line 97 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Element.php).

Comment: have you tried {{ teacher.field_classrooms|raw}} Also what spits out when you do {{ dump(teacher.field_classrooms)}} ?

Comment: Exception: Object of type Drupal\entity_reference_revisions\EntityReferenceRevisionsFieldItemList cannot be printed    and the dump just gives me the wsod

Comment: What is the field type of field_classrooms?

Comment: it is a paragraph reference, but the field type is `Entity reference revisions`

Comment: Also can you share the code where you're declaring the field_classrooms

Comment: im trying to declare the field_classrooms in the controller twig template. The field is coming from the teacher content type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to get the paragraph entity with `.entity`

```
{{ teacher.field_classrooms.entity.field_in_paragraph.value }}
```

where you can get the fields inside of the paragraph.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to print all of the fields in the entity, without writing out each one?

Comment: I don't know exactly in what kind of twig you are, but usually you should let the paragraph render by itself. If there is a problem with that, ask another question with more details.

Comment: there are multiple fields in the classrooms entity. I want to print all of them rather than typing each out. like so: `{{ teacher.field_classrooms.entity.field_in_paragraph.value }}`  I was hoping to do something more along the lines `{{ teacher.field_classrooms.entity.value }}`

Comment: It should do this.. otherwise there could be something about your setup that you aren't sharing.

Answer (score 0):

I came accross the same issue while trying to add paragraph field content manual in simplenews email twig template

I too did not find a way to use one twig statement so i used a loop...

Check how many values we have in paragraph

`{{ teacher.field_classrooms|length }}`

Getting 1st value of paragraph field

`{{ teacher.field_classrooms[0].entity.field_in_paragraph.value }}`

And this is how I used it finally: Loop trough paragraph items

`{% for entity in teacher.field_classrooms %}
    {{ teacher.field_classrooms[loop.index0].entity.field_in_paragraph.value }}
{% endfor %}`